# Use Route53 template in cloudformation with Cloudfront

Tags: json, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, devops

```
"DNS": {
           "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
           "Properties": {
             "HostedZoneId" : "Z058101PST6709",
             "RecordSets" : [{
                    "Name" : {
                        "Ref": "AlternateDomainNames"
                    },
                    "Type" : "CNAME",
                    "TTL" : "900",
                    "ResourceRecords" : {
                        "Ref": "myDistribution"
                    },
                    "Weight" : "140"
                }]
           }
        }
```

Hi Team, I am going to create a route53 record with cloudfront please find the cloud-formation code and in which I am getting an error while create a stack. Basically I want to create a CNAME record by using cloudfront domain name. Please help me out in this.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below template

```
"DNS": {
    "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
    "Properties": {
        "HostedZoneId": "Z058101PST6709",
        "Name": {
            "Ref": "AlternateDomainNames"
        },
        "ResourceRecords": [{ "Fn::GetAtt": ["myDistribution", "DomainName"] }],
        "TTL": "900",
        "Type": "CNAME"
    }
}
```

I should raise as you're using Route 53 you should take advantage of using [Alias records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) instead of `CNAME` records for your CloudFront Distribution.

This could be done via the below.

```
{
    "Type": "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
    "Properties": {
        "HostedZoneId": "Z058101PST6709",
        "RecordSets": [{
            "Name": {
                "Ref": "AlternateDomainNames"
            },
            "Type": "A",
            "AliasTarget": {
                "HostedZoneId": "Z2FDTNDATAQYW2",
                "DNSName": { "Fn::GetAtt": ["myDistribution", "DomainName"] }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris, But I guess this will not create a Record because my domain is abc.test.codavel.com where I have created a hosted zone already with a name test.codavel.com in Route53. So for that now I need to create a CNAME instead of A record. 
Correct me If I am wrong?

Comment: Getting this error by using your template 
[Tried to create an alias that targets e3o310paksk5wq., type A in zone Z2FDTNDATAQYW2, but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone]

Comment: `myDistribution` should be the CloudFront domain name @shubhamkamboj :). This hosted zone is definitely cloudfronts: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-route53-aliastarget.html :). And an A record that uses an Alias actually exhibits siilar behaviour to CNAME, the difference is that it updates the record with the IP addresses rather than AWS resource hostnames. You can use it for subdomains too, in fact its the preferred way

Comment: "Resources": {
        "myDistribution": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
            "Properties": {
                             ..........

This is my cloudfront template and thats why i am using this( myDistribution ).

So want to check should i use this myDistribution  or is there any alternative for this?

Comment: You want to use `Fn::GetAtt` like so: `{ "Fn::GetAtt": ["myDistribution", "DomainName"] }`

Comment: Yes I have used this already 
[Error] /Resources/DNS/Properties/RecordSets/0/AliasTarget/DNSName/Fn::GetAtt: Resource type AWS::CloudFront::Distribution does not support attribute {DNSName}. Rollback requested by user.
Getting this error

Comment: It should be `DomainName` not `DNSName`

Comment: @shubhamkamboj I have updated the answer with the change from above